# Behavior Difference between find('count') and find('all') cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model, controller, findall

I am having an odd problem in CakePHP where

```
$this->something->find('count');
```

works perfectly, yet

```
$this->something->find('all');
```

returns nothing (not even an empty array, any errors, or anything).

edit: turns out I am getting an sql error: "SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column" - for a column that does indeed exist. (users.display_name in the sql query below):

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, item.description, item.user_id, users.display_name FROM item LEFT JOIN users ON (item.user_id = users.id);
```

I also tried using findAllBy as well as paginate (paginate is actually what I am trying to do - although from what I've gathered, paginate and find('all') are pretty similar in functionality).

The odd thing is that find('all') works everywhere else - it's just in this specific controller that it is acting odd. I am not getting any errors, simply an empty result.

I'm thinking that I may be overlooking something quite simple, but any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the SQL output? That is usually a pretty good indicator

Comment: cakephp version? also -what exactly is find(count) returning? an integer value?

Comment: `var_dump($this->something->find('all'));` will tell you **exactly** what it returns.

Comment: So you get no output at all? Sounds like a blackhole or an out of memory issue...

Comment: @BarryChapman: The SQL output says "SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column" (for a column that does exist - so perhaps this is a problem in the model?)

Comment: @mark: cakephp version is 1.3.1, and find(count) returns an integer (the correct one)
Xeoncross: var_dump shows it as a bool(false)

Comment: and what is the correct one? 0 or a value great than zero? but it seems like your joins are not set up correctly for find(all). so it might join across unknown tables. why are you not displaying the exact cake query and the exact sql query produced in your question? nobody can help you this way.

Comment: greater than zero - approx 450, same as the total number of rows that should be returned by the find(all).

Comment: I edited to add the SQL result. It is using a join, although this seems to work fine in other controllers (from what I've seen so far).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a virtual field your your "something" model would you?

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes: I do actually - users.display_name is a virtual field that combines first and last name and helps formatting.

Comment: That's probably your problem then. It's obviously not being handled properly in that query. Virtual fields can be a little tricky sometimes. Try removing it temporarily and see if that fixes your problem. If that fixes your problem, let me know and I'll post an answer below with more details.

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes yep - that works perfectly. Interesting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as per our discussion, the problem you're having is with the virtual fields.  Have a look at the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html), more specifically at the [*virtual fields and model aliases*](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) and [*limitation of virtualFields*](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields) sections.

From your description above, it looks like you have a join specified your virtual field which would be causing the error you're seeing because it'll add the `JOIN` before the `FROM`. If you insist on using the virtual field, I'd suggest you rewrite it to use a subquery. Make sure your subquery only returns 1 column.

**Example:** (http://web-development-blog.co.uk/2011/03/08/cakephp-virtual-field-count-another-modeltable/)

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'count' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stacks Stack'
);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`Model::beforeFind`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforefind) to bind the necessary models (if necessary) and change the query parameters.

If you can't figure it out, please post your model and I'll help you.

Comment: this got me going in the right direction. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem you're having with the difference in behaviour is that `find('count')` will run a basic `COUNT(*)` query on your database to determine the number of rows.

`find('all')`, however, runs a different query, and if the SQL you've provided is what it's trying to use, it's invalid:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, item.description, item.user_id, users.display_name LEFT JOIN users ON (item.user_id = users.id);
```

There's no `FROM` declaration (`SELECT` from what, exactly?), and if you've not customised your `Item` or `User` or `App` models, (setting `$useTable = false` maybe?) you're dealing with an unusual error.

One thing to look out for, if these models work fine in other controllers, is any alteration to the properties of each model in each controller. They won't act differently on a per-controller basis unless you have code in each controller that tells it to.

Comment: ah, that's what I get for not copying and pasting. It does actually have the FROM statement (I just edited the main post to reflect that). However, that's definitely a good idea to check the per-controller differences - I'll go check out each the ones that are using this specific model.